# C# Tie ListView items with objects

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Whats the best way to tie ListView item with a object so when i move the item form one listview to another then i would be still able to tell to what object its assigned.
For example, i have object `Cards`. All these are listed in a `allCards` `ListView`. I have another `selectedCards` `ListView` and a button what moves selected items from one listview to another. When im done my selection i need to get the list of the `Card` objects what moved to the `selectedCards` ListView.

Comment: This question isn't really clear. If you moved those objects to `selectedCards`, isn't that the list you want?

Comment: @Steven: In the ListView there are only the names of the Cards..

Comment: Just a little suggestion, it would be cleaner if you'd rename allCards* to availableCards*...

Comment: Objects in C# are passed by reference, so when you move the item from one list to the next is should still be recognized as the same object. Do you perhaps create a new instance in the second list? If you create a new instance your object will have to implement IComparable interface so you could find equality. To be certain what you mean you should explain better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on @CharithJ's answer, this is how you would use the tag property:

```
    ListView allCardsListView = new ListView();
    ListView selectedCardsListView = new ListView();
    List<Card> allCards = new List<Card>();
    List<Card> selectedCards = new List<Card>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        foreach (Card selectedCard in selectedCards)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(selectedCard.Name);
            item.Tag = selectedCard;
            selectedCardsListView.Items.Add(item);
        }
        foreach (Card card in allCards)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(card.Name);
            item.Tag = card;
            allCardsListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(card.Name));
        }

        Button button = new Button();
        button.Click += new EventHandler(MoveSelectedClick);
    }

    void MoveSelectedClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in allCardsListView.SelectedItems)
        {
            Card card = (Card) item.Tag;
            //Do whatever with the card
        }
    }
```

Obviously you'll need to adapt it to your own code, but that should get you started.

Comment: I know this answer is old, but this was ***EXACTLY*** what I was looking for. I never knew the `Tag` property, nor what it did or what it was for, so thanks a bunch :D

Answer (score 5):

You could use observable collections, and create a datatemplate for your `Card` class. Then you just bind your `ListView` to the collection and it does all the work for you. When you add an item to the `ObservableCollection` the `ListView` automatically redraws.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

<ListView Name="allCardsView" Source="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type yourXmlns:Card}">
            //Your template here
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<ListView Name="selectedCardsView" Source="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type yourXmlns:Card}">
            //Your template here
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

ObservableCollection<Card> allCards = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
ObservableCollection<Card> selectedCards = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
allCardsView.DataContext = allCards;
selectedCardsView.DataContext = selectedCards;


public void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (allCardsView.SelectedItem != null &&
        !selectedCards.Contains(allCardsView.SelectedItem)) 
    {
        selectedCards.Add(allCardsView.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to say that im using WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

1st way.

Assign the object to the Tag property of the ListViewItem. Get the tags of the selected items.

2nd Way.

Add invisible subItem to the listView that holds the ID of the Card object. Then find the card by using the selected item IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Better use [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/). It is a perfect way to add and use objects with ListView. With features like Hot tracking and easy to use drag and drop your listview becomes lot simpler to manipulate.